# Weird HTML, CSS error

Tags: html, css

Current Code is here on : **[Pastie](http://pastie.org/10017955)**

For some odd reason my css works in 1 spot and not another the same style and everything. Here is what I mean.

[image]

**EDIT** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1rgkmLm/) sorry for the 8,000 lines of css but it was the easiest way to reproduce what im seeing

this is the code that creates that blue bar

```
<div class="node">
     <div class="nodeInfo categoryNodeInfo categoryStrip">
           <h3 class="nodeTitle">Donation Ranks</h3>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show some HTML/CSS code in something like jsFiddle so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you paste the related codes in the question ?

Comment: can you upload a working fiddle where in the css code can be analysed, or a working url

Comment: The code you pasted is does not have the css. Where the issue probably comes from . What you describe in your image looks like a margin thats set. But a margin does not add a white border. So you can simply use `border-top:10px solid white` To have your desired white border at the top.

Comment: @Bartdude added the jsfiddle

Comment: This is not a bug at all. There is no `margin-top` on your H3, the space you're seeing when it "works" is most probably the `padding-top` of the parent or the `margin-bottom` of the preceding element. Hard to say as despite the thousands lines of CSS the fiddle doesn't look exactly the same as your screenshot. Use the inspector of your favorite browser's developer tools and you'll see...

Comment: @Bartdude that doesnt work if i add a margin-top on the h3 it makes the blue bar bigger if i add it to any of the div's the h3 is in it does nothing even if i add a simple <br> to the code right above the divs it doesnt add a space

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the following css on the image-rounded-row css class

```
.img-rounded-row{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: table;
}
```

my error was not displaying it as a table when i tested it with turning the background black it was only maybe 10px tall but the divs inside of it were over flowing.